# How can I get the name of the type of this object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I get the type name of an instantiated object whenever it has been through a namespace?

Consider these two ways of declaring inheritence:

**Outside of a module**

With this way, there is a `function` object that is named `Shark` so whenever I ask for `myShark.constructor.name`, it returns the name of the function that `constructor` is referencing, which is `Shark`.

```
// Fish
function Fish() {
   this.fins;
}
Fish.prototype.swim = function() {
   console.log("Swim");
};

// Shark
function Shark() {
   this.teeth;
}
Shark.prototype = new Fish;
Shark.prototype.constructor = Shark;

var myShark = new Shark();
console.log("My shark is: " + myShark.constructor.name);
// Prints => My shark is: Shark
```

**Inside a module**

That's all fine, but whenever I declare an inheritance structure inside of a module, I usually structure it as below.  The problem with this is that the constructor for `Yacht` references an anonymous function.  Therefore, whenever I ask for the `myBoat.constructor.name` it has an empty string.  Is there a way that I can still get a `String` representation of the object's type?

```
var boats = (function() {
   exports = {};

   // Boat
   exports.Boat = function() {
      this.crew = 1;
   };
   exports.Boat.prototype.sail = function() {
      console.log("Sail");
   };

   // Yacht
   exports.Yacht = function() {
      this.decks = 4;
   };
   exports.Yacht.prototype = new exports.Boat;
   exports.Yacht.prototype.constructor = exports.Yacht;

   return exports;
}());

var myYacht = new boats.Yacht();
console.log("My boat is: " + myYacht.constructor.name);
// Prints => My boat is:
```

I have considered changing how I declare inheritance so that I create named functions inside the module and then expose them through `exports` as below.  Is there any other way to get the same result **without** having to make named functions and then attaching them to exports?

```
var drinks = (function() {
   var exports = {};

   // Drink
   function Drink() {
      this.calories = 130;
   }

   // Beer
   function Beer() {
      this.alcohol = 8;
   }
   Beer.prototype = new Drink;
   Beer.prototype.constructor = Beer;

   exports.Drink = Drink;
   exports.Beer = Beer;

   return exports;
}());

var myBeer = new drinks.Beer();
console.log("My drink is: " + myBeer.constructor.name);
// Prints => My drink is: Beer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be using names in function expressions:

```
// Yacht
exports.Yacht = function Yacht() {
   this.decks = 4;
};
exports.Yacht.prototype = new exports.Boat;
exports.Yacht.prototype.constructor = exports.Yacht; 
// incorrect: exports.Yacht.prototype.constructor = Yacht
// as the name is not in the scope

// ...
var myYacht = new boats.Yacht();
console.log("My boat is: " + myYacht.constructor.name);
// My boat is: Yacht
```

Note that adding the name to that function won't introduce `Yacht` into the main function's scope, so it's not the same as function declaration approach used in your third code snippet. Besides, it's more concise. )

Comment: When you say "main funciton's scope" you mean the namespace/module right?  Are there any other side effects to doing this?  If not, I'll probably take this route.

Comment: Yes, the module function; none that I know about. )